# Legend with marks and loosely dashed

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I have a problem with the visibility of the mark denoted by X **in my legend**, using a loosely dashed line. How I can make it more clear, e.g. by shifting the dashes a little to the right? (so that the mark is centered in middle of the dash line.)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
  width=\textwidth,
  legend pos = south east,
  xlabel=a,
  ylabel=b,
]
  \addplot[color=black, thick, dashed, samples=10, mark=o, loosely dashed, ,mark options=solid] {x};
  \addlegendentry{$x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mark *is* centred on the line. To make the line with a symmetric dash pattern, you can shift it with `dash phase`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
  width=\textwidth,
  legend pos = south east,
  xlabel=a,
  ylabel=b,
]
  \addplot[color=black, thick, dashed, dash phase=6.5pt, samples=10, mark=o, loosely dashed ,mark options=solid] {x};
  \addlegendentry{$x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Legend with dash pattern]

Or with

```
\addplot[color=black, thick, dashed, dash phase=2pt, samples=10, mark=o, loosely dashed ,mark options=solid] {x};
```

[image: Legend with dash patter center line]

Comment: Up voted in 10 seconds!

Comment: He needs something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBWKm.png