# PGFplots: Unexpected behavior of star marker in legend

Tags: pgfplots

Consider the example below. You'll see that if the line `%%%% TO BE COMMENTED %%%%` is commented then the blue star shape in the legend is fine.

However, it is shifted to the right otherwise, as shown in the screen shot: is this a bug?

Also, why is the star shape in the legend slightly smaller than in the plot? It does not seem to be the case for the red disk.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\pgfplotsset{legend cell align={left}} %%%% TO BE COMMENTED %%%%

\pgfdeclareplotmark{mystar}{
    \node[star,star points=5,star point ratio=0.5,draw=blue,solid,fill=blue,scale=0.75] {};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-1, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
legend entries={SO,TO},
]
\addlegendimage{semithick, red, mark=*}
\addlegendimage{semithick, blue, dashed, mark=mystar}

\addplot [semithick, red, mark=*, forget plot]
table {%
-1 0
1 1
};
\addplot [blue, semithick, dashed, mark=mystar, forget plot]
table {%
-1 1
1 0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why you are bypassing PGFPlots way of creating legend entries with `forget plot` and `\addlegendimage`, so I corrected that.
You are drawing an empty node to use as a plot mark, so it is important to set the anchor and size in the right way. I added "some more letters" to show what the `legend cell align={left}` option does.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\pgfplotsset{legend cell align={left}} %%%% TO BE COMMENTED %%%%
\pgfdeclareplotmark{mystar}{
    \node[star, star points=5, star point ratio=0.5, draw=blue, solid, fill=blue, minimum width=3pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center] {};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-1, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
]
\addplot [red, semithick, mark=*]
table{
-1 0
1 1
};
\addlegendentry{SO};
\addplot [blue, semithick, dashed, mark=mystar]
table{
-1 1
1 0
};
\addlegendentry{TO some more letters}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with two line plots and markers]

Comment: The star in the legend entry is centered on the line, but the dash pattern is not - see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/624023/8650